# Circle Progress bar animation start only after screen visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can any one help me to start the circle progress bar animation only when screen visible.

```
$('.html').ClassyLoader({
    percentage: 95
});

<div class="icon-html">
    <canvas class="html"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use jquery `scrollTop()` to detect how far the user scrolled to the bottom and than use an if statement

Comment: Thank you Mr. Vinc. But I've just little knowledge in script/jquery. I'm just copy pasting the jquery from google. Can you explain me how the function implement using my classes???

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?
html:

```
 <div class="overall">
   <div class="content">
    your content
   </div>
 </div>
```

jquery:

```
 element = $(".content").offset().top;
 $(window).scroll(function(){
   y = $(window).scrollTop();
   $('.result').html(y);
    if (y >= element){
      $('.content').show();
    }else{
      $('.content').hide().removeAttr('style');
    }
 });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v35nu75u/16/)

What this does is it waits until the user scroll to 200px of higher (lower on the page) and than he shows the div and in your case the circle

Comment: Hi @Vinc199789
Yes, like this. But I don't want to show the specific height. Just show the animation when the we scroll down to its relevant position. Please look on the html structure through the link given below.

http://jsfiddle.net/v35nu75u/12/

Comment: And waht about now. With element inspect can you see that the div is hidden when you load the screen but when you scroll down and see the white area below the blue div's that the green div also appears